# Cant seem to iterate over a column to assign sentiment values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, vader

I have tried iterating over rows in my dataframe to get sentimental values.
My code is:

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

df['Sentiment Values'] = df['Comments'].apply(lambda Comments: analyzer.polarity_scores(Comments))`
```

but it returns

`'float' object has no attribute 'encode'`

My df is:

```
  Comments

1 The main thing is the price appreciation of the token (this determines the gains or losses more 
  than anything). Followed by the ecosystem for the liquid staking asset, the more opportunities 
  and protocols that accept the asset as collateral, the better. Finally, the yield for staking 
  comes into play.

2 No problem. I’m the same. Good to hold both for sure!

3 I understood most of that. Thank you.

4 I could be totally wrong, but sounds like destroying an asset and claiming a loss, which I 
  believe is fraudulent. Like someone else said, get a tax guy - for this year anyway and then 
  you'll know for sure. Peace of mind has value too.
```

EDIT:
[image: Image of Data]

Comment: What's `analyzer`?

Comment: Im so sorry, just added the full code in now'

Comment: I have added an image of my dataset now, I have tried @tdpu code but it still didnt work and currently trying to run richardec's suggested code, which has worked.

Comment: Did you use the `df.csv` I supplied in my answer? I'm guessing there is maybe another column with floats in your data file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce - probably because the error is happening later down the dataframe than you've sent here.

I'm guessing the issue is that you've got some non-strings (floats, specifically) in your `Comments` columns. Probably you should examine them and remove them, but you can also just convert them to strings before sentiment analysis with `.astype(str)`:

```
df['Sentiment Values'] = df['Comments'].astype(str).apply(lambda Comments: analyzer.polarity_scores(Comments))
```

Comment: Just a question, what does `.astype(str)` do? Would it only alter the type

Comment: It converts all the values of the column to strings, @coder888.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute the code using a .csv file adapted from your data.

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', delimiter='_')
df['Sentiment Values'] = df['Comments'].apply(lambda Comments: analyzer.polarity_scores(Comments))
```

Note I've used an underscore as delimiter, which may not be totally robust depending on your input data.

In the dataframe, there is only a single column of comments. It looks like you may have included indices (1,2,3,4...) which could be the source of your error.

`df.csv`:

```
Comments
The main thing is the price appreciation of the token (this determines the gains or losses more than anything). Followed by the ecosystem for the liquid staking asset, the more opportunities and protocols that accept the asset as collateral, the better. Finally, the yield for staking comes into play.
No problem. I’m the same. Good to hold both for sure!
I understood most of that. Thank you.
I could be totally wrong, but sounds like destroying an asset and claiming a loss, which I believe is fraudulent. Like someone else said, get a tax guy - for this year anyway and then you'll know for sure. Peace of mind has value too.
```